# Qt6 imports with qtcreator 4.13+

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qt6

Qt6 supports importing QML modules without specifying the version number.

Example:

- Qt5: `import QtQuick 2.0`
- Qt6: `import QtQuick`

where Qt6 will just choose the newest version of the module.

My problem is, that the current version of `qtcreator` does not seem to know about this feature (or any Qt6 features, most likely). I get the following error:

[image: QtQuick import error]

Opening the Designer with this error present, results in an error message telling me, that the QML code is broken. Running the project works flawlessly. I work on Arch Linux and installed the whole `qt6` group as well as `pyside6` and the install was successful. I tried to add Qt6 functionality by choosing `/usr/bin/qmake-qt6` under *Tools > Options > Kits > Qt Versions > Add*, but this did not change anything, which does not seem surprising to me, but I thought I would try.

Is anyone else facing this problem? Have I overseen something? Can I maybe select another QML linter in an option I did not see?

Any help will be very much appreciated, I will continue to work with hardcoded version numbers for now, but I really like this new feature.

Comment: What is your kit ?

Comment: @MohammadKanan I use the Desktop Kit and I also selected Qt6 under *Qt version* in *Manage Kits*, which I forgot to mention

Comment: Ok, i am laso trying to compare with windows .. I remember I observed something unusual working on Ubuntu .. not sure what exactly .. but Qt6/QML ..

Comment: Have you managed to make this run? Also, could you chose PySide6 for new projects? I'm still stuck with 5.15.

Comment: @Noir at the moment I am still using 5.15, but with PySide6. I don't get how such an important feature as correct linting didn't make its way into the newest qtcreator version, but I guess we will have to wait until changes trickle down from Qt's commercial products. There is something about changes to imports in QML in the [changelog](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/commit/416461c8a176b0f4771a6b498db0382ff8bb6dca) for 4.15 though, maybe this fixes it